# Convert row data into different columns

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot

I have Benefit table with following data

```
id    |     Name
----------------
1     |  Shopping 
2     |  Travel 
3     |  Fuel 
4     |  Lifestyle 
5     |  Airline 
6     |  Entertainment 
7     |   Golf
```

I also have another table named Plan,  with following data

```
Plan_id   Benefit_id
---------------------
101      |      1
101      |      2
101      |      3
102      |      2
102      |      4
102      |      6
102      |      1
103      |      7 
103      |      1
104      |      4
104      |      5
```

Now, i want to display data using both the tables like following.

```
Plan_id |  Shopping |Travel |Fuel  |Lifestyle  |Airline    |Entertainment|Golf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
101     |  yes      | yes   |  yes |   no      | no        | no          | no
102     |  yes      | yes   |  no  |   yes     | no        | yes         | no
103     |  yes      | no    |  no  |   no      | no        | no          | no
104     |  no       | no    |  no  |   yes     | yes       | no          | no
```

Comment: You might want to turn off caps lock when you're not writing SQL. This is your third reminder. In fact, please turn it off now.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing your full table structure or any sample data, it appears that you can use the following with an aggregate function and a `CASE` statement:

```
select 
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Shopping' then value end) as Shopping,
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Travel' then value end) as Travel,
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Fuel' then value end) as Fuel,
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Lifestyle' then value end) as Lifestyle,
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Airline' then value end) as Airline,
  max(case when BENEFIT_CAT_NAME = 'Entertainment' then value end) as Entertainment
from yourtable
```

Or depending on your version of Oracle, you can use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from 
(
  select BENEFIT_CAT_NAME, value
  from yourtable
) x
pivot
(
  max(value)
  from BENEFIT_CAT_NAME in('Shopping', 'Travel', 'Fuel', 
                           'Lifestyle', 'Airline', 'Entertainment')
) p
```

Edit, based on your table structure and data you can use the following:

```
select p.plan_id,
  max(case when b.name = 'Shopping' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Shopping,
  max(case when b.name = 'Travel' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Travel,
  max(case when b.name = 'Fuel' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Fuel,
  max(case when b.name = 'Lifestyle' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Lifestyle,
  max(case when b.name = 'Airline' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Airline,
  max(case when b.name = 'Entertainment' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Entertainment,
  max(case when b.name = 'Golf' then 'yes' else 'no' end) Golf
from plan p
left join benefit b
  on p.benefit_id = b.id
group by p.plan_id
order by p.plan_id;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5caeb/7)